# OnItemsSourceChanged event on Inherit WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want to analyse if the columns of a datagrid will fit in current datagrid and depending of the total size of the columns, I want to change the column property to 1Star or 1Auto. I want for this to cover two events: a parent control resize and a itemssource changed. My code works very well if the parent control is resized so the logic is good but the code does not work on OnItemsSourceChanged event. I have to precise that I'm using AutoGeneratedColumns.

When I inherit the DataGrid, I tried to plug my code to the OnItemsSourceChanged event but the columns collection does not contain any columns (even once the AutoGeneratedColumns occured).

I don't get it since the DataGrid is populated correctly in my test harness tester.

I see that you can only override OnItemsSourceChanged event when you can assign delegate to other events. Is there a particular way to trigger code on a OnItemsSourceChanged event?

Comment: Consider preparing [mcve] for this and similar problems. You may solve problem while you are preparing one, otherwise you will have a much better question than now.

Comment: it's easy, inherit a datagrid in a custom control, try to override the OnItemsSourceChanged event and then see that the columns collection does not contain any column after the base event occured so after the itemssource has been replaced by the new one, very strange.

Comment: You should see the new column count in `OnAutoGeneratedColumns()`. If you don't, please post an MVCE that reproduces the issue.